# Retrieve rows in DB corresponding to particular ID using kubectl

Tags: database, postgresql, grep, containers, kubectl

I am trying to fetch the no. of rows for a particular ID using kubectl but instead getting some extra data.

**Command:**

```
kubectl exec abc-db-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d db -f /tmp/queryInstanceId.sql -v v1=full_test | grep [0-9]"
```

**Actual Output of above command:**

```
Defaulting container name to abc-db.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/abc-db-0 -n cicd' to see all of the containers in this pod.
(0 rows)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
(0 rows)
```

Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

**Note:**

> The first 2 lines always comes when we login to the DB manually but in output I only want (0 rows)

Comment: Try `grep '^([0-9]'` at the end instead of `grep [0-9]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Still the same. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines are output by `kubectl exec` because the Pod has multiple containers. It is sort of a warning that it picked the first one, which might not be the one you wanted use.

You can specify the target container in your command (`-c containername`):

```
kubectl exec abc-db-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -c abc-db -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d db -f /tmp/queryInstanceId.sql -v v1=full_test | grep [0-9]"
```

Or you can redirect the standard error with `kubectl ... 2>/dev/null` (os specific):

```
kubectl exec abc-db-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -c -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d db -f /tmp/queryInstanceId.sql -v v1=full_test | grep [0-9]" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks. Specifying the target container resolved the issue.